# Qt Pdf Cross-platform PDF reader

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, poppler

I just got in trouble with Poppler.
My program compiles for Linux/Windows/MacOS.
But it won't compile for Android. Compiler says that there is no qt5-poppler library.
Probably I need to use other lib or is there any way to make Poppler work with android compiler?

Thanks, Ivan.

Comment: Why not just compile poppler for android?

Comment: hİ @MatiasValdenegro do you have an instruction or tutorial to build poppler for android. I have been trying for hours